# CloudFront or S3 ACL: This XML file does not appear to have... AccessDenied / Failed to contact the origin

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, react-router-dom

I'm using custom domain and CloudFront for S3 static hosting site to serve https.

It's working fine when I open the pages through the app's internal buttons or link, 
but if I input direct URL in the address bar, or click the browser refresh button, it shows 
`This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.... Access Denied` error screen.

[image]

I searched related answers and tried to `/index.html` in the CloudFront general setting as `Default Root Object` but it didn't work. (Before this try, it was `index.html`)
When I updated it as `/index.html`, even the domain itself didn't work.

I have another S3 static hosting site without CloudFront and certificate just for testing. 
This site is working fine even I input direct url or click the refresh button. 
Above two S3 bucket have same settings (root object is `index.html` and error document is also `index.html`)

After this, I changed CloudFront Origin Domain Name from REST endpoint to website endpoint referred to this docs (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-website-cloudfront-error-403/)
But now getting this error when I refresh the screen.

[image]

All the object in S3 is owned to bucket owner and has public access.
This app is made by React and using react-router-dom.

Could you give me any hint or advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

My S3 bucket region requires `.` instead of `-` when I use website endpoint for cloudfront.

And FYI..
In my case, there are some little difference with the document and some tutorial. My CloudFront distribution doesn't need to use default root object, and individual objects in S3 has no public access but the bucket has it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some specific endpoints to be used for website hosting buckets, which are listed in the [Amazon Simple Storage Service endpoints and quotas document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#:%7E:text=Service%20API%20Reference.-,Amazon%20S3%20website%20endpoints,-When%20you%20configure). For example, when hosting in `eu-west-1`, cloudfront will prepopulate the dropdown with `example.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`, but if you look into the bucket settings, *Static website hosting* section, it will show you the correct url `example.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Carefully read the table! The url scheme is not fully consistent, eg. `s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` but `s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` - just to make your day a bit more joyful.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the exact same issue and was able to resolve it after taking the s3 bucket endpoint located in the properties of the s3 bucket and then pasting it into the cloudfront origins section into the origin domain. I removed the beginning of the endpoint for example: "http://website.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com" you would just remove the "http://" and then post the rest into the cloudfront origin domain and click save. That should solve the problem!

I tried all kinds of different options such as making sure every object was public as well in the s3 bucket. Make sure your s3 bucket is also publicly available.

Certain regions do have different endpoints for your s3 buckets. Here is a link that shows more of that: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-rest-api-cloudfront-error-403/